# tiling floors with 1x1, 1x2, 2x2 - how many floor tile patterns

Tags: combinatorics

Your team is a tile flooring company. You have at your disposal three types of tiles, all the same color: 1 x 1, 1 x 2, and 2 x 2 (the units are in feet). Areas to tile are in integer feet along each dimension, so it is not necessary to cut any tiles to completely cover the floor area. Sometimes your floor area is rectangular (that is, m x n feet, where m and n are both integers but are not equal to one another) and sometimes your floor area is square (that is, n x n feet, where n is an integer). You offer your clients as many different designs as possible to fit the area, so it is important that you establish a means of identifying all nonequivalent tile patterns.

•   How many unique patterns—patterns that are unique even after rotations or reflections—can you design using these tiles for floor areas 4 x 4, 4 x 5, 5 x 5, and 4 x 6 feet?

•   What techniques would you use to enumerate the various possibilities, and how can you classify them?

Anybody who has an idea of the formula to compute how many patterns in the different options?

Comment: "Be sure to describe/show your floor tiles and patterns and clearly explain your methods." Congratulations, you have convinced me that I don't want to help you with this question.

Comment: For some people, they learn visually. That is why it is a great idea to describe or show the floor tiles. But it's also great if anyone can show the formula to make the different patterns. Combination of tiles can be done through algebraic equation, but how would you show the pattern? What formula can be derive to show the pattern? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The whole question reads like something copied out of a homework assignment, and with no indication at all that you have put any thought of your own into it. "Be sure to describe..." is the way a lecturer speaks to her students, not the way someone speaks to those from whom he is trying to get help.

Comment: Sorry, I came from a third world country and english is my third language. Me and a group of friends of mine have tried to solve this and we are able to solve the combination. It is interesting to know is there's any possible formula for the pattern since we do it by the long hand which is drawing, and it is taking too long just to finish one room size... Thanks for the info though... I hope anyone can help us realize that their is a formula that exist to compute the number of patterns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be any floor shape, and consider the upper-leftmost square of the floor. There are at least one, and at most four, ways of covering that square:

- The $2\times2$ tile
- The $1\times1$ tile
- The $1\times2$ tile oriented vertically
- The $1\times2$ tile oriented horizontally

Convince yourself these are the only possibilities. For each of these possibilities, placing the tile gives you a new, smaller floor shape $T'$.

In this way you can recursively build a quaternary tree that will systematically enumerate all possible tilings. Except for very small floors doing so will be very tedious to do by hand, but it's a nice dynamic programming exercise, if you have computer science experience.

There are sometimes surprising combinatorial arguments that lead to simple formulas for these kinds of tiling problems, but I don't see an obvious one here, and I wouldn't hold my breath.